# How can we have two threads (having access to same shared instance obj) perform different logic?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads in my code created on a single Ruuanble instance (obj)
as below:

```
SampleClass implements Runnable
SampleClass obj=new SampleClass();
Thread t1=new Thread(obj);
Thread t2=new Thread(obj);
```

I want thread t1 to do addition on the variables of obj and thread t2 to do subtraction on the variables of obj.

How can i define different functionality for the two threads? If i override the run method, it will be common to both the threads.

Comment: Do not create two threads on the same object if you want different behaviour. Simple as that. Create two object of the same class with different settings, or creat two runnables of different classes.

Comment: Create two different `Runnables` that both have access to the shared object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
 import java.util.*;
   public class Main {
   int a=5;
   int b=5;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      Main ob=new Main();
       //Creating one thread 
      Thread ob1=new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(ob.a+ob.b);
        }

      }); 
       //This method wait until the ob1 thread completed
      ob1.join();
      //Creating second thread
      Thread ob2=new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(ob.a-ob.b);
        }

      }); 
       ob1.start();
       ob2.start();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hey ...which means by making use of anonymous class we define  different  logics to the two threads accessing same object ??

Comment: Yes two threads accessing the same object ie ob

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a different `Runnable` implementation to each thread:

```
String name = "Kanika Jain";
Runnable r1 = () -> System.out.println("Hello " + name);
Runnable r2 = () -> System.out.println("Hi " + name);
new Thread(r1).start();
new Thread(r2).start();
```

This is safe as String in java is immutable.

But as you mentioned, sometimes we will need to `synchronize` the data access:

```
    final int[] counter = {0};
    String name = "Kanika Jain";
    Runnable r1 = () -> {
        // do some stuff
        synchronized (counter){
            System.out.println(++counter[0]);
        }
    };
    Runnable r2 = () -> {
        // do some stuff
        synchronized (counter){
            System.out.println(--counter[0]);
        }
    };
```

You can also use `AtomicReference` if it's suitable. Specifically here, it's preferred to use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Can you please share an example where  two threads access the same object :| 
I am not able to relate this :(
I am not trying to achieve synchronization but i  want  the two threads to perform different functions on the same object

Comment: @Kanija Jain here two threads access `counter`

Comment: @Kanika Jain in the first example, two threads perform different functions on the same object

Comment: Thank u :)  @most needed rabbit